# (android) How to dynamically add items to the current nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

This picture shows the problem.

I am using `nested RecyclerView` right now.

What I want is that when the ADD button of the `outer RecyclerView` is pressed, the item of the inner `RecyclerView` is added.

But what I made is that no matter which button is pressed, the last added `inner RecyclerView's item` is added.

How can I add items each the proper `RecyclerView` position?

This is my code.

***RoutineModel.java***

```
public class RoutineModel {
    String routine;

    public RoutineModel(String routine) {
        this.routine = routine;
    }

    public String getRoutine() {
        return routine;
    }
}
```

***RoutineAdapter.java***

```
public class RoutineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<RoutineModel> routineItems = new ArrayList<>();
    public RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter;
    OnRoutineItemClickListener listener;

    public void setOnRoutineClickListener(OnRoutineItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void addItem(RoutineModel item) {
        routineItems.add(item);
    }

    public void addDetailItem() {
        detailAdapter.addItem(new RoutineDetailModel());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        detailAdapter = new RoutineDetailAdapter();
        holder.setRoutineDetailRecyClerView();
        holder.routine_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
        detailAdapter.addItem(new RoutineDetailModel());

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoutineModel curRoutineItem = routineItems.get(position);
        holder.setItems(curRoutineItem);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return routineItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView routine;
        Button addSet;
        RecyclerView routine_detail;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            initViews();

            addSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.OnItemClick();
                }
            });
        }

        private void initViews() {
            routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine);
            routine_detail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_routine);
            addSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_set);
        }
        private void setItems(RoutineModel routineItem) {
            routine.setText(routineItem.getRoutine());
        }

        public void setRoutineDetailRecyClerView() {
            routine_detail.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
            routine_detail.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
    }

    public interface OnRoutineItemClickListener {
        public void OnItemClick();
    }
}
```

***RoutineDetailModel***

```
public class RoutineDetailModel {
    String set;
    String weight;
    String reps;
}
```

***RoutineDetailAdapter***

```
public class RoutineDetailAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineDetailAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(RoutineDetailModel item) {
        items.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> getItem() {
        return this.items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_detail_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoutineDetailModel item = items.get(position);
        holder.setItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView set;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            set = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
        }

        private void setItem(RoutineDetailModel item) {
            set.setText("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

***MainActivity***

```
public class WriteRoutineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView routine_recyclerview;
    TextView title;
    RoutineAdapter routineAdapter;
    LinearLayoutManager routineLayoutManger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_routine);

        initViews();
        setPageTitle(getIntent());
        setRoutineRecyclerview();

        routineAdapter = new RoutineAdapter();
        routine_recyclerview.setAdapter(routineAdapter);

        // add detail item
        routineAdapter.setOnRoutineClickListener(new RoutineAdapter.OnRoutineItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick() {
                routineAdapter.addDetailItem();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initViews() {
        title = findViewById(R.id.body_part_detail_title);
        routine_recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.routine_recyclerview);
        add_routine_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_routine);
    }

    private void setRoutineRecyclerview() {
        routineLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        routine_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(routineLayoutManger);
        routine_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    public void addRoutine(String routine) {
        routineAdapter.addItem(new RoutineModel(routine));
        routineLayoutManger.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`detailAdapter` in `RoutineAdapter` gets re-assigned every time `onCreateViewHolder` gets called meaning it will always point to the RoutineDetailAdapter of the last item created in the `RecyclerView`.

A fix for this could be to pass the `RoutineDetailAdapter` of the clicked item with the click listener interface.

```java
public class RoutineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<RoutineModel> routineItems = new ArrayList<>();
    OnRoutineItemClickListener listener;

    public void setOnRoutineClickListener(OnRoutineItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void addItem(RoutineModel item) {
        routineItems.add(item);
    }

    public void addDetailItem(RoutineDetailAdapter routineDetailAdapter) {
        routineDetailAdapter.addItem(new RoutineDetailModel());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter = new RoutineDetailAdapter();
        holder.setRoutineDetailRecyClerView();
        holder.routine_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
        detailAdapter.addItem(new RoutineDetailModel());

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoutineModel curRoutineItem = routineItems.get(position);
        holder.setItems(curRoutineItem);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return routineItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView routine;
        Button addSet;
        RecyclerView routine_detail;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            initViews();

            addSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RoutineDetailAdapter routineDetailAdapter = (RoutineDetailAdapter) routine_detail.getAdapter();
                    listener.OnItemClick(routineDetailAdapter);
                }
            });
        }

        private void initViews() {
            routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine);
            routine_detail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_routine);
            addSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_set);
        }
        private void setItems(RoutineModel routineItem) {
            routine.setText(routineItem.getRoutine());
        }

        public void setRoutineDetailRecyClerView() {
            routine_detail.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
            routine_detail.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
    }

    public interface OnRoutineItemClickListener {
        public void OnItemClick(RoutineDetailAdapter adapter);
    }
}
```

```java
public class WriteRoutineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView routine_recyclerview;
    TextView title;
    RoutineAdapter routineAdapter;
    LinearLayoutManager routineLayoutManger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_routine);

        initViews();
        setPageTitle(getIntent());
        setRoutineRecyclerview();

        routineAdapter = new RoutineAdapter();
        routine_recyclerview.setAdapter(routineAdapter);

        // add detail item
        routineAdapter.setOnRoutineClickListener(new RoutineAdapter.OnRoutineItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(RoutineDetailAdapter routineDetailAdapter) {
                routineAdapter.addDetailItem(routineDetailAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initViews() {
        title = findViewById(R.id.body_part_detail_title);
        routine_recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.routine_recyclerview);
        add_routine_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_routine);
    }

    private void setRoutineRecyclerview() {
        routineLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        routine_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(routineLayoutManger);
        routine_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    public void addRoutine(String routine) {
        routineAdapter.addItem(new RoutineModel(routine));
        routineLayoutManger.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
    }
}
```